# How to connect from 2014 sqlserver to database with the eviroment compatibility of older version

Tags: sql-server

When I write functions or procedures in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I want to know if my code can be safely executed in older version of SQL SERVER specially when using build-in functions.
So, Is There way to convince the MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014 to simulate the older versions giving me any errors of using built-in functions of it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can control from SQL Server Management Studio related to previous version is the script export (Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting -> Script for server version). That might help you for other tasks but not for the one you want.

What you should do is go to your database's properties (with SA privileges) and change the compatibility level.

Still remember that with the new versions coming, compatibility with other versions might be dropped so you might need to maintain dedicated servers for each version you want to support (which can be costly).

Lastly you might want to write your scripts conditionally to the version it is run against (if you know the pitfalls), you might want to check this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185) which details all it is to know about SQL Server version number.